# laravel 9 route model binding with multiple optional parameters

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-9

I have this route defined:

```
Route::get('/categories/{category}/{country}/{state?}/{county?}/{city?}', ['App\Http\Controllers\LocationController', 'show'])->withScopedBindings();

public function show(Category $category, Country $country, State $state = null, County $county = null, City $city = null) {
   echo 'ok';
}
```

It's fine, automatically checks for relationships, works with 1, 2 or 3 of optional parameters. But... I want to extend it so it that the COUNTY is not always mandatory. Cause there are some cities that have direct relationship to state without county_id in the middle. Cities table has county_id and also state_id and always only one of them is present. If I add:

```
Route::get('/categories/{category}/{country}/{state?}/{city?}', ['App\Http\Controllers\LocationController', 'show'])->withScopedBindings();
```

Only one of the routes are working.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following Donkarnash answer I finally have a solution.

```
Route::get('/categories/{category}/{country}/{state?}/{county_slug?}/{city_slug?}',
    ['App\Http\Controllers\LocationController', 'show'])->scopeBindings();

public function show(
    Category $category,
    Country $country,
    State $state = null,
    $county_slug = null,
    $city_slug = null
) {
    if ($county_slug && $city_slug)
    {
        // two parameters present, that means the chain is state -> county -> city
        $county = County::where('state_id', $state->id)
            ->where('slug', $county_slug)
            ->firstOrFail();
        $city = City::where('county_id', $county->id)
            ->where('slug', $city_slug)
            ->firstOrFail();
    } else {
        if ($county_slug) {
            // one parameter present, that means the chain is state -> county OR state -> city
            $county = County::where('state_id', $state->id)
                ->where('slug', $county_slug)
                ->first();
            if (!$county) {
                $city_slug = $county_slug;
                $city = City::where('state_id', $state->id)
                    ->where('slug', $city_slug)
                    ->first();
            }
            if (!$county && !$city) {
                abort(404);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in migrations states table:

```
$table->unique(['slug', 'country_id']);
```

Counties table:

```
$table->unique(['slug', 'state_id']);
```

Cities table:

```
$table->unique(['slug', 'state_id']);
$table->unique(['slug', 'county_id']);
```

And it works. Only drawback is that if there is a county and a city with the same slug that belong to the same state. For example, county with slug "test" and state_id "15" and city with slug "test" and state_id "15". Then it won't work correctly and result as county. But usually ALL cities for a country have a chain of country -> state -> county -> city OR country -> state -> city, so this minor drawback won't affect final results for the website. Nevertheless, this also can be fixed by adjusting request validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can define two separate routes

```php
Route::get(
    '/categories/{category}/{country}/{state?}/{county?}', 
    ['App\Http\Controllers\LocationController', 'show']
)
->withScopedBindings()
->name('categories.show.county');

Route::get(
    '/categories/{category}/{country}/{state?}/{county?}/{city?}', 
    ['App\Http\Controllers\LocationController', 'show']
)
->withScopedBindings()
->name('categories.show.county.city');
```

And then check for the route name in the controller

```php
public function show(
    Category $category, 
    Country $country, 
    State $state = null
) {
    if(
        request()->route()->named('categories.show.county') &&
         request()->route()->hasParameter('county')
    ) {
        $county = County::where(
            (new County)->getRouteKeyName(),request()->route('county')
        )
        ->firstOrFail();
    }
    if(request()->route()->named('categories.show.county.city')) {
        if(request()->route()->hasParameter('county') {
            $county = County::where(
               (new County)->getRouteKeyName(),request()->route('county')
            )
            ->firstOrFail();
        }
        
        if(request()->route()->hasParameter('city')) {
            $city = City::where(
                (new City)->getRouteKeyName(),request()->route('city')
            )
            ->firstOrFail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work - need full links without query parameters for SEO purposes

Comment: @JohnStockton Have revised answer to keep everything as route parameters with two separate routes. Will this work for you?

Comment: Now it's better, but still one drawback... We can have 3 cities with same name and slug, for example - Miami (miami). Cause there are cities with the same names, they just belong to different counties or states. So if standard "scopeBindings" checks both for model existance and relationship between them, this piece of code doesn't check if children belongs to parent. When we do "$county->..." and "$city->..." we somehow need to add a where clause which checks for parent.

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: and even without this drawback, seems it still doesn't work.. It's the same as I said in the first post - I tried to add a second route without county parameters, but then only one of the routes is working (the first one that is defined in web.php). If I go "/canada/canada-state/canada-city" it says "No query results for model [App\Models\County]", although it should look for cities.